# How can I delete all the windows logs under given source name only?

Tags: c#, event-log

I need to delete all the event logs under one source name in Windows logs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127936/deleting-custom-event-log-source-without-using-code

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that selectively, you can only clear all events.